# How to customize error messages in Grails 3.3?

Tags: grails, grails3

In GRAILS it is possible to define generic erros in the i18n/messages.properties in the way

```
default.invalid.validator.message=Property [{0}] of class [{1}] with value [{2}] does not pass custom validation
```

And with the hasErrors method in GSP files the errors are shown like

```
Property [eyeColor] of [class org.application.PersonData] with value [brown] does not pass custom validation
```

Is it possible to define anywhere a translation for "property" and "class" name so error can be shown in a frienly? something like

```
Property [eye color] of [user] with value [brown] does not pass custom validation
```

Something like setting in the i18n/messages.properties file

```
org.application.PersonData=user
org.application.PersonData.eyeColor=eye color
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to define anywhere a translation for "property" and
> "class" name so error can be shown in a frienly? something like

Yes.  You can make the error message whatever you want.

See the project at https://github.com/jeffbrown/geblini18nmessages.

https://github.com/jeffbrown/geblini18nmessages/blob/94ac5402782e4dbf10f3822cecf6857ba7451096/grails-app/domain/geblini18nmessages/PersonData.groovy

```
package geblini18nmessages

class PersonData {
    String name
    String eyeColor
    static constraints = {
        eyeColor validator: { val ->
            // valid
            if(val in ['blue', 'green', 'brown']) return true

            // invalid
            return ['personData.eye.color.invalid', val]
        }
    }
}
```

https://github.com/jeffbrown/geblini18nmessages/blob/94ac5402782e4dbf10f3822cecf6857ba7451096/grails-app/i18n/geblin.properties

```
personData.eye.color.invalid=Eye color with value [{2}] does not pass custom validation
```

When validation fails, that custom validator is returning a `List`.  The first element in that `List` represents the message key that will be used to lookup the validation error message.  Every subsequent element in the `List` may be any arbitrary values that you want to put into the message.  In the message you can have variables like `{2}`, `{3}` etc. that get substituted with values in the `List`. `{0}` is the name of the property being validated.  `{1}` is the name of the domain class.  `{2}` and each subsequent index above that will correspond to values you put in the `List` after the message code.

The message you showed (`"Property [eye color] of [user] with value [brown] does not pass custom validation"`) could be achieved by definin the property like this:

```
personData.eye.color.invalid=Property [eye color] of [user] with value [{2}] does not pass custom validation.
```

It doesn't make sense to use parameters for `"eye color"` and `"user"` in this case because the error message is only used for a particular property in a particular domain.

More info at https://docs.grails.org/4.0.5/ref/Constraints/validator.html.